# Failed bind parameters using JSR223 with Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, binding, jsr223, scriptengine

Added Kotlin JSR223 support to JMeter and execute script using Kotlin language

It ignores JMeter bindings parameters, as String type `Parameters`, Tried:

```
println(Parameters)
```

Receive unresolved error:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: Error: Unresolved reference: Parameters
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.compile(KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.kt:74) ~[kotlin-compiler.jar:1.3.50-release-112]
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.compile(KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.kt:35) ~[kotlin-compiler.jar:1.3.50-release-112]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:217) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:71) [ApacheJMeter_java.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_191]
```

I tried using `$`:

```
println($Parameters)
```

Ambiguity error

```
2019-11-11 08:56:21,803 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: Error: Overload resolution ambiguity: 
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Any?): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Boolean): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Byte): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Char): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: CharArray): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Double): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Float): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Int): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Long): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Short): Unit defined in kotlin.io
javax.script.ScriptException: Error: Overload resolution ambiguity: 
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Any?): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Boolean): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Byte): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Char): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: CharArray): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Double): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Float): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Int): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Long): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Short): Unit defined in kotlin.io
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.compile(KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.kt:74) ~[kotlin-compiler.jar:1.3.50-release-112]
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.compile(KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.kt:35) ~[kotlin-compiler.jar:1.3.50-release-112]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:217) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:71) [ApacheJMeter_java.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_191]
```

It failed also using [bindings][1] as

> ```
>  println(bindings["ctx"])
> ```

Similar error:

```
 javax.script.ScriptException: Error: Unresolved reference: bindings
```

I tried also adding [importAllBindings](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/scripting-support.md), but with same results

> ```
> importAllBindings(true)
> ```

JMeter's [bindings](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/fe92fb1b46097a3585d756f9867b768440e4b53c/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/util/JSR223TestElement.java#L132) code:

> ```
>  Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
>  bindings.put("Parameters", scriptParameters); 
>  ...
>  CompiledScript compiledScript = compiledScriptsCache.get(newCacheKey);
>  ...  
>  compiledScript.eval(bindings)
> ```

If not using compiled script, error is similar

```
javax.script.ScriptException: Unresolved reference: Parameters
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.asJsr223EvalResult(KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.kt:104) ~[kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.50.jar:1.3.50-release-112 (1.3.50)]
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.compileAndEval(KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.kt:63) ~[kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.50.jar:1.3.50-release-112 (1.3.50)]
    at kotlin.script.experimental.jvmhost.jsr223.KotlinJsr223ScriptEngineImpl.compileAndEval(KotlinJsr223ScriptEngineImpl.kt:82) ~[kotlin-main-kts.jar:1.3.50-release-112]
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.eval(KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.kt:31) ~[kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.50.jar:1.3.50-release-112 (1.3.50)]
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:225) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
```

There's similar [issue](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11691) when using Scala with JSR223

> bindings parameters can't be used when using Scala engine (in other engines as beanshell,groovy,velocity,... it works)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why would you need to rope Kotlin or Scala there?

Comment: @YuriG kotlin/scala is options to use "advanced java features" without upgrading java 8, also JMeter developers start using kotlin

Comment: To me, Groovy feels more than enough (yes, BeanShell was ugly): fast, have all that modern bells & whistles + learning curve barely exists (for ones with Java knowledge). Absolutely unnecessary activity is what you're doing. Sorry for being that straightforward, but what you said didn't convince me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open an issue [KT-35113  Failed bind parameters using JSR223 with Kotlin](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-35113)